# Adding child newly created xml element by attribute using SimpleXML in PHP gives error "Attribute already exists" error

Tags: php, simplexml

I'd like to create two 'Style' children to this xml document, then add children to them. Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
    <Style id="red">
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff0000ff</color>
            <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>110000ff</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="blue">
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ffff0000</color>
            <width>1</width>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>11ff0000</color>
        </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
</Document>
</kml>
```

However, I get the error

> SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute(): Attribute already exists in...

```
$xmlstr = <<<EOL
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"/>
EOL;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$xml->addChild("Document");

$xml->Document->addChild("Style");
$xml->Document->Style->addAttribute("id", "red");
$xml->Document->Style->addChild("PolyStyle");
$xml->Document->Style->PolyStyle->AddChild("color", "110000ff"); # opacity,bbggrr
$xml->Document->Style->addChild("LineStyle");
$xml->Document->Style->LineStyle->AddChild("color", "ff0000ff"); # opacity,bbggrr
$xml->Document->Style->LineStyle->AddChild("width", "1");

$xml->Document->addChild("Style");
$xml->Document->Style->addAttribute("id", "blue");
$xml->Document->Style->addChild("PolyStyle");
$xml->Document->Style->PolyStyle->AddChild("color", "11ff0000"); # opacity,bbggrr
$xml->Document->Style->addChild("LineStyle");
$xml->Document->Style->LineStyle->AddChild("color", "ffff0000"); # opacity,bbggrr
$xml->Document->Style->LineStyle->AddChild("width", "1");
```

I thought the solution is using xpath to find the element I just created:

```
$style = $xml->xpath('Style[@id="red"]');
$style[0]->addChild("LineStyle");
```

But $style is empty and returns

> Call to a member function addChild() on null

Comment: Have a look [at the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) where they show examples of how it should be done. The method `addChild()` returns the element so store that in a variable and add all attributes etc to that specific element instance. Something like: `$el = $xml->foo->addChild('bar'); $el->addAttribute(...);` etc. When in doubt, always start by checking [php.net](https://php.net) for the function/method you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that although you call

```
$xml->Document->addChild("Style");
```

twice to add a new style element, you always set the details with

```
$xml->Document->Style->addAttribute("id", "red");
```

Doing it this method will always equate to setting the id attribute on the first Style element (it will always assume the first element when multiple elements as in `Style` are found).  So the second time you do this (with `"id", "blue"`), it will already exist from the first call (set to `"red"`).

A better way to do this is to store the return value from `addChild()` and then set the details in this element...

```
$style2 = $xml->Document->addChild("Style");
$style2->addAttribute("id", "blue");
$style2->addChild("PolyStyle");
```

etc.

The problem with your XPath expression is that you try and identify it by an attribute which can't be added until you can find the node - so a bit awkward.  You could do...

```
$xml->Document->Style[1]->addAttribute("id", "red");
```

But this means keeping track of the number of `Style` elements you have created and updating the `[1]` - which has it's risks.

Comment: Using $style2 = ...  worked. Thank you for explaining in detail.